# How to get OnUtteranceCompleted to be called?

Tags: android, onutterancecompleted

I have been surfing the web (read google/ android developer document, read stackoverflow's similar questions, read book) and very closely followed the examples. The Text-to-Speech "speak" works great. But I just can't get OnUtteranceCompleted to be called.

It must be so simple that I am not seeing the answer. Please help! Here's my code after several interactions.

Or could someone be kind enough to provide a full source code (not snippets) of one that actually works to see if it works on my emulator/ actual device?

```
public class testActivity extends Activity implements OnInitListener, OnUtteranceCompletedListener {
...

protected void checkTtS() {
    Intent checkIntent = new Intent();
    checkIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
    startActivityForResult(checkIntent, TTS_DATA_CHECK_CODE);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
....
   if (requestCode == TTS_DATA_CHECK_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS) {
         // success, create the TTS instance
         mTts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
 ....

 // Implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener.
 public void onInit(int status) {

    // status can be either TextToSpeech.SUCCESS or TextToSpeech.ERROR.
    if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
        int result = mTts.setLanguage(Locale.FRANCE);
        result = mTts.setOnUtteranceCompletedListener(this);
        HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID,"stringId");
        mTts.speak("Text to Speak",TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, params);
 ....

 public void onUtteranceCompleted(String uttId) {
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "onutterancecompleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

have you checked the value of int result after the setOnUtteranceCompletedListener call.

```
if(result == TextToSpeech.ERROR)
```

then utterance listener was not set

Comment: result is equal to TextToSpeech.SUCCESS. So setOnUtteranceCompletedListener was successfully called. But, OnUtteranceCompleted still doesn't work

Answer (score -1):

Your code probably should look like this:

```
public void onUtteranceCompleted(String uttId) {
    if (uttId.equals("stringId")) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "onutterancecompleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
 }
```

And you should also take a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/tts.html) article, there is a clear description of how `onUtteranceCompleted` works. Hope this helps.

Comment: Tried before and tried again. onUtteranceCompleted isn't called

Comment: After much trial and error, I managed to get it to work. Refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6645893/onutterancecompleted-does-not-get-called). And really make sure to put all code in //UI Changes. Otherwise, some features do not work, e.g. Toast