# Android text to speech setOnUtteranceCompleted not applicable

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I'm trying to get the activity to finish after it's finished speaking but for some reason I cannot fathom it tells me that the setOnUtteranceCompleted not applicable for text to speech.  I'm new to android programming so please be gentle  :-)

Here's the code...

```
public class SpeakActivity extends Activity implements OnUtteranceCompletedListener{

    Random randnum = new Random();
    TextToSpeech tts = null;
    private boolean ttsIsInit = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_speak);
        // Show the Up button in the action bar.
        setupActionBar();
        startTextToSpeech();
    }

    void startTextToSpeech(){
        final int randint = randnum.nextInt(4);
        final String text = ((GlobVars) this.getApplication()).getResponse(randint);
        tts = new TextToSpeech(this, new OnInitListener() {
            public void onInit(int status) {
                tts.setOnUtteranceCompletedListener(this);
                if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
                    ttsIsInit = true;
                    if (tts.isLanguageAvailable(Locale.ENGLISH) >= 0){
                        tts.setLanguage(Locale.ENGLISH);
                    }
                    tts.setPitch(0.5f);
                    tts.setSpeechRate(0.5f);
                    if (tts != null && ttsIsInit) {
                        Log.d("got ere", "spoken");
                        tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }


    // shut down tts to free the TTS resources
   @Override
   public void onDestroy() {
      if (tts != null) {
        tts.stop();
        tts.shutdown();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
 }


    @Override
    public void onUtteranceCompleted(String arg0) {
        ((GlobVars) this.getApplication()).setListen(true);
        this.finish();

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am ot sure but as per the docs of [setOnUtteranceCompletedListener()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#setOnUtteranceCompletedListener%28android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.OnUtteranceCompletedListener%29), you might need to use [TextToSpeech.OnUtteranceCompletedListener listener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.OnUtteranceCompletedListener.html) as an argument. I think the way to use the function is as below. Note that use `runOnUIThread` method in case you want to make any changes to the UI on the call of the onUtteranceCompleted function.

```
TextToSpeech tts= new TextToSpeech(context, new OnInitListener() {
    @Override
    public void onInit(int status) {
        tts.setOnUtteranceCompletedListener(new OnUtteranceCompletedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onUtteranceCompleted(String utteranceId) {
                //Do things here
            }
        });
     }
});
```

Source of above : Check [onUtteranceCompleted does not get called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6645893/onutterancecompleted-does-not-get-called) question.

Hope this helps.